# Click on a button that triggers a function in model - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am trying to make a bookmark function on my Laravel blog to bookmark a post. I have this function in my User.php modal

```
public function bookmark($object)
    {
        if($this->isBookmarked($object)) {
            return $this->bookmarks()->where([
                ['bookmarks.post_id', $object->id]
            ])->delete();
        }
    
        return $this->bookmarks()->create(['post_id' => $object->id]);
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out how to trigger the function above when the user clicks on this button in my bookmarks.blade.php file

```
<button type="submit"><i class="bi bi-bookmark-heart-fill text-2xl ml-4"></i></button>
```

Is there any equivalent of the javascript onclick function in Laravel?

Comment: You could use forms with a hidden input that submit to your route

Answer (score 0):

no there is no javascript onclick function in Laravel, but you can use the javascript onclick event to make an ajax request to your laravel route to trigger the function

Example

```
<button type="submit" onclick="addBookmark({{ $blog->id }});"><i class="bi bi-bookmark-heart-fill text-2xl ml-4"></i></button>
```

and the js function

```
function addBookmark(blogId){
    $.ajax('/yourDomainAndYourRoute', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: { blog_id: blogId },
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        // handle the success part
    },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        // handle the failed part
    }
    });
}
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: That is jQuery specific code. Is there a vanilla JS equivalent? Submitting a form would be kind of the same as onclick